# Restore purchase button always returns previously bought product for sandbox user Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, in-app-purchase, skproduct

Let me describe what have I done.
I start & stop observing In-App purchase in my app delegate like this:

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
IAPManager.shared.startObserving()
```

And in `applicationWillTerminate`:

```
IAPManager.shared.stopObserving()
```

These are the functions in my IAPManager class:

```
func startObserving() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
}

func stopObserving() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
}
```

I know for sandbox user the purchase time frames are as below:

```
1 week = 3 minutes
1 month = 5 minutes
2 months = 10 minutes
3 months = 15 minutes
6 months = 30 minutes
1 year = 1 hour
```

But It doesn't match with the sandbox user testing. After crossing this time span If I tap on the "Restore Purchase" button, It still gives me all of my previously bought Product ids.

My Restore code:

`PurchaseViewController`:

```
func restorePurchases() {
    IAPManager.shared.restorePurchases { (result) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch result {
            case .success(let success):
                if success {
                    self.restoredProductSuccessfully()
                    self.didFinishRestoringPurchasedProducts()
                } else {
                    self.didFinishRestoringPurchasesWithZeroProducts()
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                self.showIAPRelatedError(error)
            }
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

`IAPManager class`:

```
//Handler
var onBuyProductHandler: ((Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void)?

func restorePurchases(withHandler handler: @escaping ((_ result: Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void)) {
    onBuyProductHandler = handler
    totalRestoredPurchases = 0
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
```

`SKPaymentTransactionObserver` delegate methods:

```
extension IAPManager: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    //This delegate will trigger for every transactions, either for purchasing or restoring
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        transactions.forEach { (transaction) in
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                onBuyProductHandler?(.success(true))
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                
            case .restored:
                totalRestoredPurchases += 1
                let prodID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier
                print("restored productID \(prodID)")
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

            case .failed:
                if let error = transaction.error as? SKError {
                    if error.code != .paymentCancelled {
                        onBuyProductHandler?(.failure(error))
                    } else {
                        onBuyProductHandler?(.failure(IAPManagerError.paymentWasCancelled))
                    }
                    onBuyProductHandler?(.failure(error))
                    //print("IAP Error:", error.localizedDescription)
                }
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                
            case .deferred, .purchasing: break
            @unknown default: break
            }
        }
    }
    
    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        if totalRestoredPurchases != 0 {
            onBuyProductHandler?(.success(true))
        } else {
            print("IAP: No purchases to restore!")
            onBuyProductHandler?(.success(false))
        }
    }
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
        if let error = error as? SKError {
            if error.code != .paymentCancelled {
                print("IAP Restore Error:", error.localizedDescription)
                onBuyProductHandler?(.failure(error))
            } else {
                onBuyProductHandler?(.failure(IAPManagerError.paymentWasCancelled))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this delegate method at line `print("restored productID \(prodID)")` I am always getting all of my previous product identifier although they suppose to be expired. What  am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing that you need to look at the date of the restored products. You get all purchases, even past purchases.  You need to look at the end date for subscriptions to determine if they are still valid or not.

Comment: @Paulw11 First all of thanks a lot for your comment. So are you saying It is suppose to give all previous purchase history? And I need to get the end date from each transaction and compare with current date and time? One more question, there's only one date I can get from `SKPaymentTransaction` which is transactionDate. Is this the end date you were talking about?

Comment: You need to look at the receipt to determine the end date for subscription purchases https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. To get purchasing history I can follow 2 separate ways. One is `Refresh receipt` which gives the last purchasing details and the second one is `Restore completed transaction`. Now my question is, when I restore a product, I get back a `transaction` object in the delegate `updatedTransactions`. If I want to get purchasing details (purchasing date, expiration date) from this `transaction` object, what should I do?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your suggestions. I have done the receipt validation by communicating directly from my app to App Store server with the help of `App Specific secrete key`. But I have couple of queries. I posted a new question regarding this. Can you please take have a look on it? Thanks!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70985272/whats-the-user-of-transaction-in-updatedtransactions-delegate-method-for-in